# How to compare two adjacent strings in one column and traverse all the strings?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

The function I used to find difference between two strings ([found on the R-help website](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Comparing-diffing-strings-td2336741.html)):

```
X  <- "abcdefg" ; Y <- "aBcDEfg" 
diff <- function(X,Y){
  X0 <- unlist(strsplit(X,split=""))  ## Nasty but necessary! 
  Y0 <- unlist(strsplit(Y,split=""))  ## ... 
  ix <- which(X0 != Y0) 
  cbind(ix,X0[ix],Y0[ix])   
}
diff(X,Y)
     ix         
[1,] "2" "b" "B"
[2,] "4" "d" "D"
[3,] "5" "e" "E"
```

The column in the data frame status I need to compare :

```
grint <- 
c("45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", 
"45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "<5CCBC:4B", 
"<5CCBC:4B", "<5CCBC:4B", "<<CCBC::B", "<<GGBG::E", "<<GGBG::E", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "CC11B1CCE", 
"CC11B1CCE", "CC55B1CCE", "55CCBC44B", "55CCBC44B", "55CCBC44B", 
"55CCBC44B", "55CCBC44B", "55CCBC44B", "G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", 
"G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", 
"G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", 
"G1CCBC1GB", "G1CCBC1GB", "91CCBC11B", "01CCBC11B", "01CCBC11B", 
"01CCBC11B", "01CCBC11B", "11CCBC11B", "11CCBC11B", "11CCBC11B", 
"15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", 
"15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", "15CCBC11B", 
"55CCBC11B", "55CCBC11B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", 
"55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B"
)
```

I need to compare the values in the column successively, that means it can find the difference happened and compare the two strings. For example, `grint[9]` and `grint[10]` are different and show it. 
I tried to use `lapply` function to accomplish a loop to apply to each string to find every changes, but I failed:

```
a <-grint[i]
b <-grint[i+1]

lapply(grint,diff(a,b))
```

the error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'diff(a, b)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

So I wonder how I should do this? Thanks very much!

Comment: Try `diff(grint[-1], grint[-length(grint)])`

Comment: I suppose it's safe to say you were looking for output like that produced by [the code where you found it on the R help site](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Comparing-diffing-strings-td2336741.html).

Comment: Oh,I should have added the link. Thank you for the reminder, I will remember it next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than my answers below, just do what @Andrie suggested `diff(grint[-1], grint[-length(grint)])` in the comment.

Here are two slightly different approaches, which can handle strings of differing lengths.  If all the strings are of the same length, you don't need `str_pad` from `stringr`

```
samplestrings <- c("apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "apple", "apple","aslkd;fa")
library(stringr)
samplestrings <- str_pad(samplestrings, max(nchar(samplestrings)) , side="right")

  X0 <- unlist(strsplit(samplestrings,split=""))  ## Nasty but necessary!
  Y0 <- unlist(strsplit(c(samplestrings[-1], rep(" ", max(nchar(samplestrings)))),split="")) ## ...
  ix <- which(X0[-length(X0):-(length(X0)-max(nchar(samplestrings))+1)] != 
              Y0[-length(X0):-(length(X0)-max(nchar(samplestrings))+1)])
  cbind(ix,X0[ix],Y0[ix])

      ix          
 [1,] "9"  "a" "b"
 [2,] "10" "p" "a"
 [3,] "11" "p" "n"
 [4,] "12" "l" "a"
 [5,] "13" "e" "n"
 [6,] "14" " " "a"
 [7,] "25" "b" "a"
 [8,] "26" "a" "p"
 [9,] "27" "n" "p"
[10,] "28" "a" "l"
[11,] "29" "n" "e"
[12,] "30" "a" " "
[13,] "42" "p" "s"
[14,] "43" "p" "l"
[15,] "44" "l" "k"
[16,] "45" "e" "d"
[17,] "46" " " ";"
[18,] "47" " " "f"
[19,] "48" " " "a"
```

---

Approach 2:
I wrote this one first before I realized what sort of output OP was looking for, but it can still be used if you want to create a data frame of the mismatches in the process of looking for the character differences between consecutive strings.

```
samplestrings <- c("apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "apple", "apple","aslkd;fa")
library(stringr) 
# use str_pad to make every string equal in number of characters
samplestrings <- str_pad(samplestrings, max(nchar(samplestrings)) , side="right")

findiffs <- rle(samplestrings)

newdf <- data.frame(index = paste0(cumsum(findiffs$length),"-",cumsum(findiffs$length)+1), 
          firststring = samplestrings[cumsum(findiffs$length)],
          secondstring = samplestrings[cumsum(findiffs$length)+1])

newdf <- newdf[-dim(newdf)[1],] 

  index firststring secondstring
1   2-3    apple        banana  
2   4-5    banana       apple   
3   6-7    apple        aslkd;fa
```

So, `newdf` contains the non-identical strings, then we can use the approach you were using:

```
  X0 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(newdf$firststring),split=""))  ## Nasty but necessary!
  Y0 <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(newdf$secondstring),split=""))  ## ...
  ix <- which(X0 != Y0)
  cbind(ix,X0[ix],Y0[ix]) 

     ix          
 [1,] "1"  "a" "b"
 [2,] "2"  "p" "a"
 [3,] "3"  "p" "n"
 [4,] "4"  "l" "a"
 [5,] "5"  "e" "n"
 [6,] "6"  " " "a"
 [7,] "9"  "b" "a"
 [8,] "10" "a" "p"
 [9,] "11" "n" "p"
[10,] "12" "a" "l"
[11,] "13" "n" "e"
[12,] "14" "a" " "
[13,] "18" "p" "s"
[14,] "19" "p" "l"
[15,] "20" "l" "k"
[16,] "21" "e" "d"
[17,] "22" " " ";"
[18,] "23" " " "f"
[19,] "24" " " "a"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's almost what I need. I wonder it is only only find all the differences between adjacent strings, but also compere each character in strings. like: '  diff("apple","banana")
     ix         
[1,] "1" "a" "b"
[2,] "2" "p" "a"
[3,] "3" "p" "n"
[4,] "4" "l" "a"
[5,] "5" "e" "n"'

Comment: @Chenlu Sure.  Feel free to upvote useful answers, and once you get the right answer or the answer you like best, feel free to accept it, as that is how the site works ;)  Also, in the future, it would be good to provide the desired output so that it is explicit what you are looking for.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion:) Haven't understood the rules well coz I am quite a newbie both programming and the site.

Comment: @Chenlu I updated my answer with two slightly different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `match`, which returns the index of first match. Removing the first element,

```
> ( m <- match(unique(x), x)[-1] )
 [1] 10 13 14 16 45 47 48 54 68 69 73 76 86
```

And comparing the match to the previous element, we can see that a difference has ocurred.

```
> cbind(x[m-1], x[m])
      [,1]        [,2]       
 [1,] "45CCBC44B" "<5CCBC:4B"
 [2,] "<5CCBC:4B" "<<CCBC::B"
 [3,] "<<CCBC::B" "<<GGBG::E"
 [4,] "<<GGBG::E" "55CCBC41B"
 [5,] "55CCBC41B" "CC11B1CCE"
 [6,] "CC11B1CCE" "CC55B1CCE"
 [7,] "CC55B1CCE" "55CCBC44B"
 [8,] "55CCBC44B" "G1CCBC1GB"
 [9,] "G1CCBC1GB" "91CCBC11B"
[10,] "91CCBC11B" "01CCBC11B"
[11,] "01CCBC11B" "11CCBC11B"
[12,] "11CCBC11B" "15CCBC11B"
[13,] "15CCBC11B" "55CCBC11B"
```

Comment: +1 I like the approach, but I think you're missing the last pair: `"55CCBC11B" "55CCBC41B"` because `"55CCBC41B"` occurs in two sections of the vector.  There may be occasions when more than the first match is desired (see `which(grint=="55CCBC41B")`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question.     If it is that you are trying to find where the differences exist in the column/variable ? you could do this.

- turn your column into a character vector.

I have taken your first 17 entries here and manually put them into a vector 'x'

```
x<-c("45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B",     "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "45CCBC44B", "<5CCBC:4B", "<5CCBC:4B", "<5CCBC:4B", "<<CCBC::B", "<<GGBG::E", "<<GGBG::E", "55CCBC41B", "55CCBC41B")
```

Then you could simply ask if each element of that vector is the same as the previous one doing a lagged comparison:

```
lagged.x <- c(NA,head(x,-1))
x == lagged.x


[1]    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

That would identify with "FALSE" where the differences exist.   If that's what you were interested in?